# Wrong RGB values are returned

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, rgb, mouselistener

I am trying to get the RGB value of a pixel of an image. (The pixel that the mouse is over). Here is the code which adds the image and the code which attends to the mouse ::

```
/// I got this code somewhere from StackOverFlow; 
///Couldn't find the link; 

label = new JLabel();
            try {
// THIS PICTURE IS NOT MINE                
targetImg = ImageIO.read(new java.net.URL("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFAhy8GM1F3_TyPjG7ezbeFRUy00PN4hpJCA&usqp=CAU"));
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(rescale(targetImg)));
           

            panel1.add(label);

            fields = new JPanel();
            fields.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            red = new JTextField(3);
            green = new JTextField(3);
            blue = new JTextField(3);
            red.setEditable(false);
            green.setEditable(false);
            blue.setEditable(false);
            fields.add(red);
            fields.add(green);
            fields.add(blue);
            panel1.add(fields);
            
      label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                try{
                    int packedInt = targetImg.getRGB(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    Color color = new Color(packedInt, true);
                    fields.setBackground(color);
                    red.setText(Integer.toString(color.getRed()));
                    green.setText(Integer.toString(color.getGreen()));
                    blue.setText(Integer.toString(color.getBlue()));
                   }
                   
                   catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception)  { }
                     }
            });
            
             } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This runs and compiles fine; However, sometimes the color returned by the RGB is not the color my mouse is on; Here is a pic ::

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5qIx.png

Note: The white cross is an approximate location of where it is; A screenshot apparently does not take the mouse too.

The code is also laggy. Sometimes it hangs on one pixel and I have to wait until it runs again.

Why does this happen, and what can I do to prevent this? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does `rescale` do? If it does what its name says, Shouldn't you be calling `getRGB` on the rescaled image, rather than the original?

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem, so we don't have to ask questions like the one above. *Sometimes it hangs on one pixel* - don't use an empty catch block. How do you know when you have an Exception if you don't have any Exception code? You should be displaying the Exception message. I would guess you are getting the Exception because you have a rescaled image.

Comment: Note, if you want to prevent the lag you should run any GUI code on the EDT thread using invokeLater like so `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){fields.setBackground(color);;}});`

Answer (score 1):

Since you only provided a code snippet, I created the following GUI.

[image: RGB Processor]

Since the picture was so small, I put it under the RGB display.

The main problem was matching coordinate systems so that the mouse pointer would point to the pixel in the image.  When you put the image inside a `JLabel`, you have to translate the mouse coordinate to an image coordinate.

I sidestepped the coordinate system problem by creating a drawing `JPanel`.  By drawing the image on a drawing `JPanel` and adding the `MouseMotionListener` to the drawing `JPanel`, the mouse coordinates match the image coordinates.

I started the Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created a `JFrame`, an RGB `JPanel`, and a drawing `JPanel`.  The `JFrame` methods must be executed in a specific order.  This is the order I use for all my Swing applications.

The RGB `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` to separate the red, green, and blue `JTextFields`.

The drawing `JPanel` draws the image.  The drawing `JPanel` is the same size as the image.  Again, by drawing the image on a drawing `JPanel` and adding the `MouseMotionListener` to the drawing `JPanel`, the mouse coordinates match the image coordinates.

I made the `ColorListener` a separate class.  I basically copied your code to the `mouseMoved` method.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the classes inner classes so I could paste this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RGBProcessor implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RGBProcessor());
    }
    
    private BufferedImage image;
    
    private Color panelColor;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private JPanel rgbPanel;
    
    private JTextField redField;
    private JTextField greenField;
    private JTextField blueField;
    
    public RGBProcessor() {
        this.panelColor = Color.RED;
        this.image = getImage();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(this, image);
        this.rgbPanel = createRGBPanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RGB Processor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(rgbPanel, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createRGBPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(panelColor);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        redField = new JTextField(4);
        redField.setEditable(false);
        panel.add(redField);
        
        greenField = new JTextField(4);
        greenField.setEditable(false);
        panel.add(greenField);
        
        blueField = new JTextField(4);
        blueField.setEditable(false);
        panel.add(blueField);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private BufferedImage getImage() {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new URL("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/"
                    + "images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFAhy8GM1F3_TyPjG7ezbe"
                    + "FRUy00PN4hpJCA&usqp=CAU"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public void setPanelColor(Color color) {
        this.panelColor = color;
        this.rgbPanel.setBackground(color);
    }
    
    public JTextField getRedField() {
        return redField;
    }

    public JTextField getGreenField() {
        return greenField;
    }

    public JTextField getBlueField() {
        return blueField;
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private BufferedImage image;

        public DrawingPanel(RGBProcessor frame, BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), 
                    image.getHeight()));
            this.addMouseMotionListener(new ColorListener(frame, image));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ColorListener extends MouseAdapter {
        
        private RGBProcessor frame;
        
        private BufferedImage image;
        
        public ColorListener(RGBProcessor frame, BufferedImage image) {
            this.frame = frame;
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
            int packedInt = image.getRGB(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Color color = new Color(packedInt, true);
            frame.setPanelColor(color);
            frame.getRedField().setText(Integer.toString(color.getRed()));
            frame.getGreenField().setText(Integer.toString(color.getGreen()));
            frame.getBlueField().setText(Integer.toString(color.getBlue()));
        }

    }

}
```